# Convert a sample text file into hierarchical JSON

Tags: json, gson

Sample text file:

```
+employeeName => xyz //Root Element 1
    ++address => abc //Child of Root 1
        +++zipcode => 123 // innerchild element
            ++++ location => pqr
    ++dob => 13/10/1995 // child of ROOT 1
+employeeName => abc
```

here '+' represents Root element and '++' represents Child element

I'd want to generate the following JSON (Java)

```
{  
   "employeeName":{  
      "xyz":{  
         "address":{  
            "abc":{  
               "zipcode":{  
                  "123":{  
                     "location":"pqr"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "dob":"13/10/1995"
   },
   "employeeName":"abc"
}
```

Comment: You did not define your textual format at all, and the single example you give is confusing (is `+` and `=>` part of the input, or is it your annotation about it)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Gelatin https://github.com/knipknap/Gelatin/wiki

Use a grammar to define your input text and specify json as your output format.

Comment: can we do this in java ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to ***specify* the input file text format**, possibly using some [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) notation, in some document (or perhaps some comment).

<sup>(an example, or even a set of them, is *not* a specification of a format)</sup>

Once you have *defined* the input format, you just need to **write a [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)** for it and **define some** in-memory **[abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)** (AST) **representation** inside your converter. There are zillions of tools and techniques for [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) (or tokenization) and [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing), e.g. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) for Java, [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/) & [Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) for C, Ocamllex & Menhir for Ocaml, etc...). See also wikipage on [compiler-compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler). Read some textbooks about compilation (e.g. the [dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)).

Once you have parsed your data into some kind of [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST), emitting a JSON for it is a piece of cake.